# Preload content efficiently in PageViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I am working on an application that displays content of different types. Each page (viewController) consists of two layers: A video layer looping a video, and a layer above displaying images or Gifs within a WebView. That is a lot of Data to process.

Is their a way to kind of preload that content efficiently so that on the one hand the transition between the pages is smooth (that is my biggest problem at the moment) and on the other hand, the RAM does not overflow.

Currently I am Storing the ViewControllers an an Array. With each page turn, the after next controller is loaded, including its views.

Thank you for answering.

Comment: Use uicollectionviewcontroller and only store data in array (like video url, image url etc) and then deque cell(vith viewcontroller.view in it)

Comment: First of all, don't use gif images - convert them to h.264 to reduce memory consumption. A 300KB h.264 video will be 20MB as a gif, and the gif is lower quality.

Comment: @AndriusSteponavičius So you think that a UICollectionView is the appropriate way? Each page should be displayed fullscreen, not in a grid like in the galery.

Comment: Yes thats easy just make collectionView cell size the same as controller view size, CollectionViews are built exactly for this reason, so you can have views that are the same displaying the different content, where you can reuse the views, and change the content

Comment: Okay thank you very much. I'll give it a try

Comment: I tried what you proposed above. I used dequeReusableCellWithIdentifier. Unfortunately this also leads to memory problems